# Assign a value to duplicates in Python

Tags: python, pandas

I'm interested  in assigning values to duplicate rows  in  a Pandas  dataframe as below. The dataframe is  below:-

```
data_1 = {'ID': ['001', '003', '001','002','002','002'], 'Name': ["XX1", "XX3", "XX1", "XX2", "XX2", "XX2"]} 
df = pd.DataFrame(data_1)
```

The  output  should be something  related to the output of  df2.

```
output = {'ID': ['001', '003', '001','002','002','002'], 'Name': ["XX1", "XX3", "XX1", "XX2", "XX2", "XX2"],"Number": [1, 1, 2, 1, 2,3]} 
df2 = pd.DataFrame(output)
```

How  can I autoincrement  the "Number" on duplicated "ID"?

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66489613/pandas-group-by-and-rank-within-group-based-on-multiple-columns help?

Comment: Yes it does @KarlKnechtel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `groupby` + `cumcount` (adding 1 as the counts are from 0):

```
df['Number'] = df.groupby('ID').cumcount().add(1)
```

Output:

```
    ID Name  Number
0  001  XX1       1
1  003  XX3       1
2  001  XX1       2
3  002  XX2       1
4  002  XX2       2
5  002  XX2       3
```

Answer (score 0):

As per @Barmar's response, this  seems  to have answered it. More details  are found [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.0/generated/pandas.Series.rank.html)

```
df["rank"] = df.groupby("ID").rank("first", ascending=False)
```